# Generate URL from random row in text file?

Tags: php, arrays, url, random, share

I have a plain text file with quotes, where each quote is on its own line (and nothing more). I display a random quote on a webpage with the following code.

```
<?php
$f_contents = file("quote.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
echo $line
?>
```

Is it possible to generate a link to the random quote so that someone can find it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is probably GET method.

That means you add `?quote=5` as an example when you want quote 5.

But if nothing is passed by GET the show a random.
The if also checks that it's a numeric value that is passed in the GET and that it's not a higher number (row number) than there is in the txt file.

```
$f_contents = file("quote.txt");
if(!isset($_GET['quote']) || !is_numeric($_GET['quote']) || $_GET['quote'] > count($f_contents)){
    $random = array_rand($f_contents);
    $line = $f_contents[$random];
    echo $line . "<br>\n";
    echo "<a href='www.example.com/quote.php?quote=" . $random . ">Link to this quote</a>";
}else{
    $line = $f_contents[$_GET['quote']];
    echo $line
}
```

Change the anchor link to suit!